# The "most active" users tab for a proposal shows deleted answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

If you look at the [Food & Cooking proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1288/food-and-cooking) on Area51 you can see this, it's also shown in the following image:

http://localhostr.com/files/ed8d59/Screen+shot+2010-08-12+at+6.30.10+PM.png

The question ["What kind of bologna..."](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4831/what-kind-of-bolgona-works-best-to-remove-paint-from-a-car) was deleted over two days ago.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, we had been pulling in all all questions and answers, deleted or not, for display on Area 51.

This is fixed now, so deleted posts shouldn't appear on Area 51 for longer than an hour.